# How can I install Oracle JDK on FreeBSD_10.3

Tags: java, installation, freebsd, oracle

I've fetched jdk-8u102-i586.tar.gz from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html

and already place it in /usr/ports/distfiles directory.

But, "make install" command prints same message when I first command make install without jdk file fetch.

How can I solve it?

This image is my terminal message.

---

after I fixed command, `make install` still does not work with following message:

[image]

Comment: Check the filename carefully.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably follow the instructions you see after running `make install`. You were supposed to get `jdk-8u102-linux-i586.tar.gz` (Java SE Development Kit 8u102).

[image: Instructions]

Comment: Oh, Sorry. I missed "-linux-" in that command. It works well. But I faced new problem...